# /bin/sh: 1: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found

Tags: gcc, eclipse-cdt, cross-compilation

I'm working on eclipse indigo on Ubuntu 12.04. And I'm trying to cross compile so I downloaded gcc-4.4-arm-linux-gnueabiarm-linux-gnueabi-4.4 and I changed the C/C++ Build setting and I added includes and library to my path. But it tells me that it doesn't find the arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc. can somebody help me out? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need the `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` package, rather than just `gcc-4.4-arm-linux-gnueabi`; the former supplies the `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` symlink.